# Can someone share the reason for the results of Locust testing differs from jmeter testing?

Tags: jmeter, difference, locust, web-api-testing

I have run the JMeter testing with 400 concurrent users with a 125 loop count for the following GET request.

> [https://example.com/rest_api?from_pt={from_point}](https://example.com/rest_api?from_pt=%7Bfrom_point%7D)

[image]

I have run the same request in locust with 500 concurrent users and 100 spawn rate per second and get the following charts

[image]
[image]
[image]

Locust file containing code

```
import csv
from locust import HttpUser, task

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    def on_start(self):
        pass
    @task(1)
    def request_testing(self):
        with open("test.csv", 'rt') as f:  
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in reader:           
                from_point = row.get('from_point')
                to_point = row.get('to_point')
                headers = {'content-type': 'application/json','q':'{{api_key_value}}'}
                
                self.client.get("rest_api?from_pt=%s" %(from_point),headers=headers)
```

**I need to find where I was wrong in doing locust testing.**

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see any JMeter test results, you're looking at [PerfMon metrics](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) (usage of CPU, RAM, etc.). Moreover it's not clear how did you configure and run JMeter test ([Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings, etc.)

Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the JMeter [.jtl test results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) and compare it with Locust results.

In general comparing 2 load testing tools output doesn't make a lot of sense, if you're running the same test (in terms of number of concurrent users,sending the same request payload at the same rate, etc.)  you should be getting the same results